# Change in Android Studio's Vector Asset import

Tags: android, android-studio

Guys, I noticed when I import an `SVG` using vector asset import of Android Studio in recent versions, I get a smaller image than before. Here is an example:

**Image which was imported before:**

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="240"
    android:viewportWidth="240" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#d82727"
        android:pathData="m220,194c0,-7.236 -2.487,-13.342 -7.688,-18.312 -4.975,-4.975 -11.081,-7.688 -18.312,-7.688s-13.342,2.487 -18.312,7.688 -7.688,11.306 -7.688,18.312c0,7.236 2.487,13.342 7.688,18.312 5.201,5.201 11.306,7.688 18.312,7.688 7.236,0 13.342,-2.487 18.312,-7.688 5.201,-4.975 7.688,-11.081 7.688,-18.312m-17.642,-14.248 l5.88,6.106 -8.366,8.366 8.366,8.366 -5.88,5.88 -8.366,-8.366 -8.366,8.366 -6.106,-5.88 8.366,-8.366 -8.366,-8.366 6.106,-6.106 8.366,8.366z" android:strokeWidth="2.261"/>
</vector>
```

[image: Old image]

**Same image imported now:**

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="240"
    android:viewportWidth="240" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#d82727"
        android:pathData="m223,201c0,-5.287 -1.817,-9.748 -5.617,-13.38 -3.635,-3.635 -8.096,-5.617 -13.38,-5.617s-9.748,1.817 -13.38,5.617 -5.617,8.261 -5.617,13.38c0,5.287 1.817,9.748 5.617,13.38 3.8,3.8 8.261,5.617 13.38,5.617 5.287,0 9.748,-1.817 13.38,-5.617 3.8,-3.635 5.617,-8.096 5.617,-13.38m-12.89,-10.41 l4.296,4.461 -6.113,6.113 6.113,6.113 -4.296,4.296 -6.113,-6.113 -6.113,6.113 -4.461,-4.296 6.113,-6.113 -6.113,-6.113 4.461,-4.461 6.113,6.113z" android:strokeWidth="1.652"/>
</vector>
```

[image: New image]

I don't know when this change has occurred, but is there any way to import image with similar scale like before? I somehow don't like to edit/import all images for getting similar results like before.

Comment: Change your viewport height and width to android:viewportHeight="24" and android:viewportWidth="24"

Comment: @MdMobinurRahman I cannot change viewport, because image is designed on that view port. size is changed by `height` and `width` but I don't know why this is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The preview part is just a demo. Your image has not changed

But you can give the vector the width and height
Doesn't this help you?

```
<vector android:height="{custom size}" android:viewportHeight="240"
        android:viewportWidth="240" android:width="{custom size}" 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <path android:fillColor="#d82727"
            android:pathData="m223,201c0,-5.287 -1.817,-9.748 -5.617,-13.38 -3.635,-3.635 -8.096,-5.617 -13.38,-5.617s-9.748,1.817 -13.38,5.617 -5.617,8.261 -5.617,13.38c0,5.287 1.817,9.748 5.617,13.38 3.8,3.8 8.261,5.617 13.38,5.617 5.287,0 9.748,-1.817 13.38,-5.617 3.8,-3.635 5.617,-8.096 5.617,-13.38m-12.89,-10.41 l4.296,4.461 -6.113,6.113 6.113,6.113 -4.296,4.296 -6.113,-6.113 -6.113,6.113 -4.461,-4.296 6.113,-6.113 -6.113,-6.113 4.461,-4.461 6.113,6.113z" android:strokeWidth="1.652"/>
    </vector>
```